# Flatten all inner lists that do not have sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

As the title says, I would like to flatten all inner lists, excluded the ones that do not have sublists. For example, from

```
lis = {a, {b, {d, f}}, {{c, k, {h, l}}, e}, {{{{a}}}}};
```

I would like to have

```
myFlatten[lis]

{a, b, {d, f}, c, k, {h, l}, e, {a}}
```

I have a solution, but probably is inefficient and not elegant.
The steps are the following:

- change the `Head` of all `List` subparts that do not have members of type `List`, to something else, say `myList`
- `Flatten` the resulting expression
- change back `myList` to `List`

this is my implementation:

```
notListQ[z_] := Head[z] =!= List;

myFlatten[list_List] := Module[{myList, tempList},
  tempList = list /. List[y__?notListQ] -> myList[y];
  tempList = Flatten[tempList];
  tempList /. myList -> List
]
```

This obviously can be shortened to

```
myFlatten[list_List] := Module[{myList},
  Flatten[list /. List[y__?notListQ] -> myList[y]] /. myList -> List
]
```

Any errors in my implementation?
Better solutions?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ReleaseHold[Flatten[MapAt[Hold, lis, Position[lis, _List?VectorQ]]]]
```

> {a, b, {d, f}, c, k, {h, l}, e, {a}}

Comment: Another variant is `ReleaseHold @ Flatten @ Replace[lis, l_List :> Hold[l], {-2}]`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about `VectorQ`, and never understood well the semantic meaning of `Hold` and `ReleaseHold`.

Comment: Yet another variant: `ReleaseHold[Flatten[Map[Hold, lis, {-2}]]]`

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. I like the simplicity of your solution

Answer (score 6):

```
Apply[## &, lis, -3]
Apply[Sequence, lis, -3] (* thanks J.M. *)
Map[## & @@ # &, lis, -3]
Replace[lis, {a__} :> a, -3]
FlattenAt[#, Position[#, {__}, -3]]& @ lis
```

all give

> {a, b, {d, f}, c, k, {h, l}, e, {a}}

Also, with

```
parts = Join @@ Most /@ Rest @ GatherBy[Position[lis, List], First];
```

you can use `ReplacePart`,`MapAt`, `FlattenAt` or `Part` assignment:

```
ReplacePart[lis, parts -> Sequence]
MapAt[Sequence &, lis, parts]
FlattenAt[lis, Most /@ parts]
Module[{l = #}, (l[[##]] = Sequence) & @@@ #2; l] &[lis, parts]
```

> {a, b, {d, f}, c, k, {h, l}, e, {a}}

Finally, you can do in-place assignment:

```
(lis[[##]] = Sequence) & @@@ parts; lis
```

> {a, b, {d, f}, c, k, {h, l}, e, {a}}

Comment: Another one: `Apply[Sequence, lis, -3]`

Comment: @J.M. yes! Thank you.